# How to check for OL events in Vue?

Tags: openlayers, vue.js

I would like to observe things like `maps.on('moveend')` to update zoom level or center values. Currently I have a "construct" made up of `computed` params and `watcher` functions like this:

```js
export default {
  [...],
  // Computed values are saved / read from vuex store
  computed: {
    currentLatLon: {
      get () {
        const obj = {
          lat: this.$store.getters.getCurrentLat,
          lon: this.$store.getters.getCurrentLon
        }
        return obj
      }
    },
    moveEnd: {
      get () {
        const val = this.olMap !== null
          ? this.olMap.on('moveend', () => {
              console.log('moveEnd; do something... getCenter()...'))
            }
          : false
        return val
      }
    }
  },
  watch: {
    currentLatLon (value) {
      console.log('watcher currentLatLon invoked: value =', value)
      // this.zoomToCurrentLocation()
    },
    moveEnd (value) {
      console.log('moveEnd: value =', value)
    }
  }
}
```

codesandbox with minimal code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/openlayers-getzoom-74gnw?file=/src/components/MapContainer.vue

It works so far. But I am unsure, because it seems to be "double the trouble".

Is there a better way to observe Openlayers events in Vue?

Comment: At least for me it's not clear what "the issues" are and what the actual problem/question is.

Comment: The question is, if the solution with Vue watchers is the proper way to listen to Openlayers' change events.

Comment: Then edit your question and pose a single question, without this and that update and without mentioning issues, if there are none.

Comment: I shortend the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answer this myself, maybe one day it helps somebody else:

OpenLayers event listeners are setup in Vue's "mounted" lifecycle hook. The function such an event listener calls is then defined regularly in "methods".

Example (Vue 2):

```js
export default {
  data(() => {
    olMap: null,
    geolocation: null,
    [....]
  },
  mounted() {
    this.olMap = new Map({ ... })
    this.olMap.on('moveend', this.onMoveEnd)

    this.geolocation = new Geolocation({ ... })
    this.geolocation.on('change', this.onChange)
    this.geolocation.on('change:accuracyGeometry', this.onChangeAccuracyGeometry)
    [...]
    this.geolocation.on('error', this.onError)
  },
  methods: {
    onMoveEnd () { ... }
    onMoveChange () { ... }
    onChangeAccuracyGeometry () { ... }
    onError () { ... }
  }
}
```